# custom htaccess redirect rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have 3 redirect rules I'm trying to implement on a wp installation:

```
RewriteRule ^job/(.*)$ /job?jid=$1  [NC]

RewriteRule ^jobs/(.*)$ /category?cid=$1  [NC]

RewriteRule ^domain/(.*)$ /domain?did=$1  [NC]
```

Out of those three only the first one actually works, the rest gives me a 404 or redirect to an existing page if the parameter is close to one of the existing wp pages.
Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try and add `L` to your flags, so you get `[NCL]`, otherwise default Wordpress rewrite rules might apply on your rewrite targets.

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html